# Multiple Bouncing Balls

Tags: java

```
public class BouncingBalls
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{    
  double[] balls = new double [10];
  double[] x = new double[1];
  double[] y = new double[1];
  double[] xspeed = new double[1];
  double[] yspeed= new double[1];

  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
     x[i] = 0.5;
     y[i] = 0.5;

     double r = 0.05;

     xspeed[i] = Math.random() / (5 * 24);
     yspeed[i] = Math.random() / (5 * 24);

     while(true)
     {
        StdDraw.clear();
        StdDraw.circle(x[i],y[i],r);
        x[i] = x[i] + xspeed[i];
        y[i] = y[i] + yspeed[i];

        if (x[i] > 1 || x[i] < 0)
           xspeed[i] = xspeed[i] * -1;

        if (y[i] > 1 || y[i] < 0)
           yspeed[i] = yspeed[i] * -1;

        StdDraw.show(1000/ 24);
     }          
     }     
    }
 }
```

I need to print 10 bouncing balls onto the screen and i can not figure out what i am doing wrong that it wont print all 10.
I do not know how to use any of the import methods or any thing like that. so if someone could please help me that would be great!!!

Comment: its a way to draw the circle out

Comment: Your doubles for xspeed and yspeed and x and y have only one element when I am assuming you mean 10

Comment: yes, but where's the implementation? that's not a standard Java class

Comment: @Doorknob I "think" it comes from the ACM package??

Comment: @MadProgrammer Well I don't see any imports or anything remotely related to some `StdDraw` thing...

Comment: @Doorknob Tend to see it bit, it seems to be a "teaching" API...

Comment: i was told to use StdDraw. i just need to know why it will not print out all 10 "balls"

Comment: What DOES it print out?

Comment: it only prints out one bouncing ball

Comment: BECAUSE IT GETS STUCK IN THE INFINITE LOOP.

Comment: then what should i change the while loop to?

Answer (score 1):

Your draw loop is inside of your for loop.  Generally in animation, your draw loop should be the outermost loop.

```
public class BouncingBalls
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {    
        int balls = 10;
        double[] x = new double[balls];
        double[] y = new double[balls];
        double[] xspeed = new double[balls];
        double[] yspeed= new double[balls];

        double r = 0.05;

        /* initialize balls */
        for(int i = 0; i < balls; i++)
        {
            x[i] = 0.5;
            y[i] = 0.5;

            xspeed[i] = Math.random() / (5 * 24);
            yspeed[i] = Math.random() / (5 * 24);
        }

        /* draw loop */
        while(true)
        {
            StdDraw.clear();
            for(int i = 0; i < balls; i++)
            {
                /* Draw and update a ball */
                StdDraw.circle(x[i],y[i],r);
                x[i] = x[i] + xspeed[i];
                y[i] = y[i] + yspeed[i];

                if (x[i] > 1 || x[i] < 0)
                    xspeed[i] = xspeed[i] * -1;

                if (y[i] > 1 || y[i] < 0)
                    yspeed[i] = yspeed[i] * -1;
            }          
            StdDraw.show(1000/ 24);
        }     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might start by changing you while(true) loop, which will never terminate.

Comment: I believe that's the intention. Also, this isn't an answer, it's just a comment.

Comment: we are suppose to use true in the while loop so it only ends when i ned it

Comment: Then you need to do something in the loop to cause it to terminate.

Comment: @ScottHunter No he doesn't, it's supposed to loop infinitely

Comment: that has nothing to do with the question I am trying to figure out

Comment: An infinite loop INSIDE a for loop -- great design.